# Time between button press and release in python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to time from the start of a button press to the end of a button press on GPIO (in order to differentiate between a long press and a short press). I want to use a callback to get the button presses immediately and without polling. Here is what I tried first:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

def my_callback(channel):
    start = time.time()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.FALLING)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    print(elapsed)

GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)

#while other stuff is running
```

On running this program I get:

> RunTimeError: Conflicting edge detection already enabled for this GPIO channel.

Because I can't poll both I tried:

```
def my_callback(channel):
    GPIO.remove.event.detect(25)
    start = time.time()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.FALLING)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    print(elapsed)    

GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)
```

This worked once but was not repeatable because I am removing the event detection and redefining it. Thus I tried to restore the event detect in the callback:

```
def my_callback(channel):
    GPIO.remove.event.detect(25)
    start = time.time()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.FALLING)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    print(elapsed) 
    GPIO.remove.event.detect(25)   
    GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)

GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)
```

This finally worked, but will crash my pi quickly, as I think I created a loop-back. Is there another way to accomplish this that I am overlooking?

Comment: What if you comment out/remove everything in the callback that starts with `GPIO` and change `GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback)` to `GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)` *outside* the callback function?

Comment: That yielded a callback on button push as well as button release. Since I commented out all GPIO in the callback the number returned is microseconds.

Comment: *"That yielded a callback on button push as well as button release. "* Yep, that's what I was hoping for. I would use that to do something like this: When you receive the callback (happens both on press and release), you do a reading of the pin value to determine if the button is currently being pressed or was just released. You also log the time but only after subtracting the current time from the previously logged time. I can probably post some working code later if you don't figure it out on your own

Comment: That did the trick! I have edited my post to reflect the new code. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! You're welcome

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to jDo here is the code that works

```
def my_callback(channel):
    global start
    global end
    if GPIO.input(25) == 1:
        start = time.time()
    if GPIO.input(25) == 0:
        end = time.time()
        elapsed = end - start
        print(elapsed)

  GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=200)
```